# Canonical urls for Visualforce pages

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I have Salesforce sites using VF pages. The urls are similar to

https://abc.my.salesforce-sites.com/apex/positions?id=xxxxxxxxxx

Is there a way we can have these urls to use a more canonical names. These urls need to be passed on to another application which only accepts cannonical urls.

Is there anything that can be done to achieve this?

Comment: Are you meaning the fact that the ID is a query parameter rather than a path step is a problem for your external system?

Comment: Yep. anything with ?id=xxxxx&a=3444 is an issue.  This is for integration with indeed apply

Comment: If you're using Sites you can create a [URL rewriter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm). Otherwise you could create your own (REST API) URL handler that can respond with a 302 redirect to the appropriate URL. You then just have to send your flavour of URL to the external system...

Comment: @PhilW Thanks url rewriter was the path  i took to get it working

Comment: Glad you got things working. You should post an answer to help future visitors!

Comment: @PhilW added in answer, Let me know your thoughts and if that can be improved

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @phil for pointing me in the right direction.

My requirement required me to create a canonical url that would be used to in an xml which would be sent to an external system and the external system would post those urls in their website. So when someone would click those urls we should be able to process that url.

To generate the url i ended creating a formula field in the object which basically used the name of the record

url would be like

https://www.abc.com/shjob/name/id

https://www.abc.com/shjob/Software_Engineer/ae889990038

Note Giving the id directly throws an error while processing the url in the urlrewrite class. Not sure of the reason why. For that reason i ended up adding  a prefix to the id. So the url would be something like this

https://www.abc.com/shjob/Software_Engineer/shrp_ae889990038

I use this formula field to populate in the xml.

Now when someone clicks on the url the salesforce site would say page not found as it cant find the url. To process this url we need to write an urlrewiter class. Refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm

In my case i just needed to map the url to the correct url in sites.

```
global class URLRewriter implements Site.UrlRewriter {
    final String VISUALFORCE_PAGE = '/Detail?id=';
    final String DIRECTORY = '/shjob/';
    global PageReference mapRequestUrl(PageReference  myFriendlyUrl){
        System.debug('myFriendlyUrl ' + myFriendlyUrl);
        String url = myFriendlyUrl.getUrl();
        String posId;
        System.debug('url ' + url);
        if(url.contains(DIRECTORY)){ // i need this to happen only if the url has this directory
            System.debug('contains directory url ' );
            if(url.endsWith('/')) // remove the slash at the end
            {
                url = url.removeEnd('/');
            }
            posId = url.substringAfterLast('/'); // get the id from url
            if(posId.contains('shpid_'))
            {
                posId = posId.removeStart('shpid_'); // remove the prefix on the id 
            }
            System.debug('posId ' +VISUALFORCE_PAGE + posId);

            return new PageReference(VISUALFORCE_PAGE + posId); // redirect it to the right url in sites
       
    
        }
        return null;
    }

    global List<PageReference> generateUrlFor(List<PageReference>   mySalesforceUrls){
        System.debug('mySalesforceUrls ' + mySalesforceUrls);
        return null;
    }
}
```

To implement the urlrewriter on sites, go the sites and edit the site and select the rewriter class on the url rewrite lookup. Make sure you give access to this apex class as well.

Hope this helps.
If somebody has a better way of doing this i would love to hear it